# How to represent a D3DCOLOR (32-bit ARGB) in Java?

Tags: java, graphics, directx, xml-rpc

I need to represent a DirectX D3DCOLOR (which is a 32-bit ARGB) in Java.

I don't need to perform any operations on it, other than string encoding it to transport over XML-RPC to a DirectX application.  It's very likely to enter my Java system in a similar way, i.e. as an encoded string.

What string form would be considered "canonical", or rather, what string representation will be the friendliest for my DirectX client to parse?

Therefore, what type should I use within Java to capture a D3DCOLOR?  The immediately obvious answers are:

- Keep it as a `java.lang.String`, and don't bother validating it
- Wrap a `java.lang.Long` and implement some `toString()` method

Neither seems wholly satisfactory, but I suppose it depends on how the client would prefer me to serialize it.

Comment: I think it's 4 hex number together, but I'm not sure it's ARGB or RGBA, something like this 0X336699FF, where FF is alpha here

Comment: Yes, this depends on the client side, D3DCOLOR is a DWORD which in turn is unsigned long, but java does not have unsigned type, you can use type long instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that ARGB channels are restricted to a single byte they are usually stored as a `byte[]` or some equivalent-in-size structure. An obvious equivalent would be a 4-byte int/uint. This is doubly-useful when you consider that D3DXCOLOR [can be constructed from a DWORD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

EDIT: Although Java doesn't support unsigned, this doesn't really matter as a C++ cast will turn it back around.